# MapView in TabActivity

Tags: android

In my application I am using tabHost and TabWidget with 5 tabs..On Tab1, I want to show Map with current locaion..Here my

```
            currentActivity extends TabActivity
```

But in Tab1(daeafult tab1), I want to show map with current location...Pls help

Answer (score 0):

check below example

http://vkroz.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/programming-android-%E2%80%93-map-view-within-tab-view/

Comment: Yes I already Implemeted this tutorials but It is showing an error:MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.

Comment: how come!!!!..in that tutorial only they given comments its working fine like that Make sure the uses-library line: uses-library android:name=”com.google.android.maps”
is within the application tags in the manifest.xml